# Unable to Set Java Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel

I have downloaded a look and feel for java. it is Quaqua. it is downloaded in ZIP format. my question is how to add this look and feel to my program? i am using NetBeans 8. i googled and found not suitable result.
So tell me proper procedure. 
Thanks.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html

Comment: "So tell me proper procedure". No, we won't, unless you tell us what you *actually tried*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a jar file to classpath like any other lib and and before showing your JFrame you set lnf like this:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(quaqualnf);
...
JFrame frame = ...
```

If you bothered to look on the dev guide, you'd have found this:

```
public class MyApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         // set system properties here that affect Quaqua
         // for example the default layout policy for tabbed
         // panes:
         System.setProperty(
            "Quaqua.tabLayoutPolicy","wrap"

         );

         // set the Quaqua Look and Feel in the UIManager
         try {
              UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                  ch.randelshofer.quaqua.QuaquaManager.getLookAndFeel();
              );
         // set UI manager properties here that affect Quaqua
         ...
         } catch (Exception e) {
             // take an appropriate action here
             ...
         }
         // insert your application initialization code here
         ...
     }
}
```